# Alterar titulo texto menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, plugin-wordpress

Olá.

Eu comprei o tema de uma loja para woocommerce, e eu gostaria de alterar o texto do menu de opções, como eu faço ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Tenta entrar no arquivo functions.php do tema e procura o trecho onde tem esse nome tipo:

```
'name' => _x('Produtos', 'post type general name'),
```

ou

```
'singular_name' => _x('produtos', 'post type singular name'),
```

E altera o nome, mas somente onde tem nome, caso contrário você compromete o funcionamento, pois ai nesses 2 itens são apenas rótulo. Eu não mexo com temas prontos mas se estiver assim fica mais facil, dá um ctrl+F pra pesquisar o nome 8Theme Options e vê se está dentro de 'name'. Mas faça um backup por favor!